# pthread_create is not accepting arguments

Tags: c, pthreads, arguments

I am trying to create a pthread and I am confused on the arguments required to create it.

I am trying to pass multiple arguments into the entry function for the pthread and I encapsulated that into a struct. However, `pthread_create` is not accepting it.

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
    Customer_Spawn_Params *params = (Customer_Spawn_Params*) malloc(sizeof(Customer_Spawn_Params));
    params->probability = chance;
    params->queue = queue;

    pthread_t customer_spawn_t;
    if (pthread_create(&customer_spawn_t, NULL, enqueue_customers, &params)) {
    }
```

And here is the `Customer_Spawn_Params` struct:

```
 typedef struct {
        Queue *queue;
        double probability;
} Customer_Spawn_Params;
```

Finally, here is the `enqueue_customers()` which accepts a pointer to `Customer_Spawn_Params` struct:

```
    void *enqueue_customers(Customer_Spawn_Params *params) {
        int customer_id = 0;
        double probability = params->probability;
        Queue *queue = params->queue;
        while(true) {
                sleep(1);
                bool next_customer = next_bool(probability);
                if (next_customer) {
                        Customer *customer = (Customer*) malloc(sizeof(Customer));
                        customer->id = customer_id;
                        enqueue(queue, customer);
                        customer_id++;
                }
        }
        return NULL;
}
```

Comment: `However, pthread_create is not accepting it.`..how did you arrive at this conclusion?

Comment: When calling `pthread_create` you're passing the last argument (the argument to the thread function) as a pointer *to the pointer*. Unless you change your thread function, you will have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: cast your parameter to (void*) and your thread proc should accept void*

Comment: @NatashaDutta I have syntastic checker that is marking it as wrong.

Comment: Also, the `pthread_create` function expects the function to take a `void *` argument.

Comment: @dvhh, the argument itself casts perfectly to `void*` in C, it is the function prototype that is wrong.

Comment: @JensGustedt I find it better practice to enforce the cast

Comment: Wow so many responses so fast! I love Stack Overflow!

Comment: @dvhh, the type `void*` is made exactly for that purpose. Casts make code completely unreadable and the best programs don't contain any of them.

Comment: OT: It's not a good idea to make a variable name look like a type name: `customer_spawn_t`

Comment: params is already a pointer, so there is no need to get its' address.  Most likely the thread is getting the parameter, but it is getting an address of an address ptr.  Try removing the & from the thread create call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Point 1.**

`if (pthread_create(&customer_spawn_t, NULL, enqueue_customers, &params))`

change to

`if (pthread_create(&customer_spawn_t, NULL, enqueue_customers, params))`.

Because, `params` is a pointer itself.

**Point 2 :**

Also,

```
void *enqueue_customers(Customer_Spawn_Params *params)
```

should be

```
void *enqueue_customers(void *params)
```

In your function, you have to typecast it back to the actual pointer , for example,

```
void *enqueue_customers(void *params)
{
   Customer_Spawn_Params *p = params;
```

Comment: please don't cast `void*` to something. This is completely superfluous and may actually hide problems.

Comment: @JensGustedt OK sir, thanks. Can you please elaborate or link to a post which elaborates a little bit[maybe with a small example]?

Answer (score 2):

Your function `enqueue_customers` doesn't have the correct prototype. It should be

```
void *enqueue_customers(void* p) {
  Customer_Spawn_Params *params = p;
  ...
```